# javascript / jQuery functions not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**UPDATED**:

Thanks for some good feedback. I did have multiple faults in my code, but

My problem was actually with a string in my code inside my jquery/javascript functions (that I did not post here, because I didn't think of it as faulty)

Faulty string:

```
var deleteAnswer = prompt("Are you sure you want to delete this project?\nName: "+<?=$project['projName']?>+"\nCompany: "+<?=$project['compName']?>);
```

Correct string:

```
var deleteAnswer = prompt("Are you sure you want to delete this project?\nName: <?=$project['projName']?>\nCompany: <?=$project['compName']?>");
```

I will also switch to only use `document.ready`, instead of `window.load`

And I use Firefox, but will start to check for errors in F12 console -> errors

JSHint was also a nice tip, as I can check my code there.

Thanks a lot for your feedback guys! =)

---

I've been using javascript and jquery on my page now, and it's been working good until now.

For some reason none of my code inside my `<script>` tag will fire anymore. Maybe I'm missing something important.

I've removed some of the code but I hope this is enough information.
I've checked the source code to see if it's pointing to the right js file, and it is.

Also, adding this code right before `<title>` also works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

});
</script>
```

Anyways, here's parts of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!--<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>title goes here</title>

</head>

<body>
<script>
    <!-- ########## WINDOW.load ############### -->
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#topBarWrapper').hover(function() {
            $('#topBarDropDown').stop();
            $('#topBarDropDown').animate({top:'-30px'});
        }, function() {
            $('#topBarDropDown').stop();
            $('#topBarDropDown').animate({top:'-60px'});
        });

        $('#deleteProjectBtn').click(deleteProject);
        $('#cancelProjectBtn').click(cancelProject);

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    });

    function someFunction(){
        //do something
    }

    function cancelProject(){
        window.location = 'admin.php';
    };

    <!-- ########## DOCUMENT.ready ############### -->
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert("document is ready");
        var myCompSelector = document.getElementById('fcompanySelection');
        myCompSelector.selectedIndex = parseInt(<?=$project['companyID']?>)-1;

        var myCatSelector = document.getElementById('category');
        myCatSelector.selectedIndex = parseInt(<?=$project['categoryID']?>)-1;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `<!-- ########## WINDOW.load ############### -->` isnt that the format for comments in HTML? You should use `// ########## WINDOW.load ###############`

Comment: what do you expect from `$(window).load()` ([fyi](http://api.jquery.com/load/))? as usual : any console error (F12)?

Comment: Should I understand your first document ready handler as an abstract example of the one I see below in you code example or do you have two handler functions?

Comment: can you specify your error?

Comment: @Bondye: yep, he is in JS not HTML context, that could yield a nice js error, which stops execution, I guess you nailed it.

Comment: changed <!-- to //.. No change. I'm not sure why I use both window.load and document.ready, but sometimes my code only works in one of them. Not it doesnt work in any of them:P

Comment: No error. But none of the code executes. None of my functions are working, and I cant see any errors.

Comment: Your WINDOW.load comment and the other one that says DOCUMENT.ready, that comment format is only for HTML as far as I know, change it from "<!--" to "//"

Comment: @TechHunter Ohhh.. Didn't know of that console error thingy! Very nice. I see errors on missing ).. So I'll just have to find that missing ) =)

Comment: A session with a nice debugger (Firefox Firebug or Chrome), setting break points and spreading some console output, should give you fast insight of what is going on.

Comment: @StianBergLarsen another nice trick, go to jsfiddle.net and use the JSHint button. your code is here http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/MRZSh/ . bty you have some PHP parts in there

Comment: What does this render as? ` <?= $project['companyID'] ?> `

Comment: gives the ID of the current company (which is linked to a name of the company in MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<script>

    function someFunction(){
        //do something
    }

    function cancelProject(){
        window.location = 'admin.php';
    };

    /** ########## DOCUMENT.ready ############### **/
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        alert("document is ready");
        $('#topBarWrapper').hover(function() {
            $('#topBarDropDown').stop();
            $('#topBarDropDown').animate({top:'-30px'});
        }, function() {
            $('#topBarDropDown').stop();
            $('#topBarDropDown').animate({top:'-60px'});
        });

        $('#deleteProjectBtn').click(deleteProject);
        $('#cancelProjectBtn').click(cancelProject);

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });


        var myCompSelector = document.getElementById('fcompanySelection');
        myCompSelector.selectedIndex = parseInt(<?=$project['companyID']?>)-1;

        var myCatSelector = document.getElementById('category');
        myCatSelector.selectedIndex = parseInt(<?=$project['categoryID']?>)-1;
    });

</script>
```

- use `//` for inline comment, `/* ... */` for comment blocks `/** ... **/` for documentation purpose comment blocks
- `.load()` is an Ajax method to load remote content into an element use `$(document).ready(function(){})` or `$(function(){})`
- dunno if it's intentionnal but you also have PHP parts which won't execute client side :

  ```
      var myCompSelector = document.getElementById('fcompanySelection');
      myCompSelector.selectedIndex = parseInt(<?=$project['companyID']?>)-1;

      var myCatSelector = document.getElementById('category');
      myCatSelector.selectedIndex = parseInt(<?=$project['categoryID']?>)-1;
  ```
- remember to always try with the **Debugger Console** (F12 button on chrome) first then make a stripped **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** with minimalist code to reproduce the error. If you do this most of the time your code will be already debugged while narrowing down the bug.
- prefer `console.log('text here or even javascript objects')` rather than `alert()`

Here is an exemple with your code (I've commented out the PHP part so it can run)  :
http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/MRZSh/

Comment: Thanks for your very informative feedback. The php code I use does not need to be run on the server side. I fetch some data at the very beginning of the document that I use in other parts, so it works in my example (as this information is already fetched before the code runs.

Comment: @StianBergLarsen php not server side? how can this be :S anyway np :)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that the php code gets data from my database before I use my functions, and that data is then "static" when used in my functions =)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your comment :

`<!-- ########## WINDOW.load ############### -->`

This works in only HTML or XML. What you need is:

`//########## WINDOW.load ###############`

Or

`/* ########## WINDOW.load ############### */`

Answer (score 1):

From comment to answer:

Your format for comments is wrong.

```
<!-- HTML Comment -->

// Javascript single line

/*
   Javascript
   Multiple lines
*/
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments

### Edit

I can see you use `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Also you say that `<script type="text/javascript">` work and `<script>` doesn't.

So you probably need to add `<script type="text/javascript">` in the body instead of `<script>`

Or change to `<!doctype html>` which is support by every browser.

Comment: Thanks. But that was not the problem in my example. But good information to know! =)

Comment: Hmm, forgot about the newer html, as I didnt seem to need functions from that. Would it screw up anything for me if I switch to using html5? <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: No it is backward compatible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5